# What are the main problems programmer should be aware of while using ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am writing new directive that is going to use ***ng-repeat*** to create nested child's and more. What I have seen so far is there are all kind of problems using this great tool of angular. You get a great binding to data, but when data increases, you are going to suffer from very low performance and defects hard to be solve. This is making the all directive very hard to maintain and reuse.

So I wanted to ask all of you who have a lot of experience with AngularJS, what are the best things to be aware of in order to use it properly and not doing huge mistakes.

Did you ever think not using it and just make your own loop?
Be glad to hear your points.

Comment: Is the problem really related to ng-repeat? Or is just that more data handling means more strain on a system? Aren't you just pushing against the edges of performance and memory availible on some systems?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s quickly recap how we can use ng-repeats (along with optional filters):

```
<div ng-repeat="stock in ctrl.stocks | filter:someCondition">

</div>
```

We can also use ng-repeats to iterate over objects (In case you hadn’t known this):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, stock) in ctrl.stocksMap | filter:someOtherCondition">

</div>
```

where stocksMap is an object map, where the key is the id of the stock, and the value is the individual stock object. One common misunderstanding now is how AngularJS creates and displays the UI, based on this ng-repeat. This is how AngularJS works under the covers (in a nutshell) when you use ng-repeat:

1. It iterates over each item in the array (or each key, value in the
   object)
2. It runs each item via any filters that are present in our
   expression, to check if it should be displayed or not
3. It calculates a hash value by which it identifies the object (which
   is by reference by default)
4. It checks if it has already created a DOM element for the hash value
   previously If so, it reuses it
5. If not, it creates a DOM element based on the ng-repeat template
6. All the DOM manipulations are taken and inserted in an optimal
       manner into the actual DOM
7. A watch is added on the array, which triggers step 1 again if the
   array undergoes any change

For More information you can refer this [LINK](http://www.befundoo.com/blog/optimizing-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/)

Comment: Is there a problem using ng-repeat being binded to a very large data in json format? I mean, does the size of the json being repeated is important? I do have a very large JSON data and I wonder if the size of that data is really matter.